# libgdx - glClear takes too much time

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Method `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` is taking too much time, around 15ms

Here is the code sample:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;//this is almost always > 15 ms
System.out.println("render time total: " + end);
```

This is on my android device (nexus 5), on my pc its 2-3 ms

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate way to measure it. For one thing, these methods probably return before the action is completed on the GPU.

Comment: @Tenfour04 In that case wouldn't i get smaller times than it actually takes to execute those functions? 15ms is way to much for clear, that leaves me with only 1-2ms for my code if i want to run on 60fps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is as expected. You're measuring the frame rate, not the execution time of `glClear()`.

To understand what is happening here, you need to be aware that the GPU operates asynchronously to your CPU code. For example, when you call `glClear()`, you're submitting a command that tells the GPU to clear the framebuffer. The easiest way to picture how this works is that the command is added to a queue, which is processed by the GPU at a later point.

One consequence is that the framebuffer has generally not been cleared when the `glClear()` call returns. So measuring the time spent in the call is mostly unrelated to how long it takes to actually clear the framebuffer.

So what are you measuring? It's basically the frame rate. Android does not let you produce frames faster than the screen refresh rate, which is typically 60 Hz or slightly higher. At 60 Hz, the display shows a new frame every 16.667 ms, which is almost exactly the time you are measuring.

Your rendering needs to be throttled to match the display refresh rate, otherwise you would be producing frames at a much higher rate, and would queue up more and more work. The throttling could potentially happen anywhere, but it is fairly common to block the app at the start of a new frame when enough work is already queued up.

I believe most Android systems use triple buffering. This means that if two undisplayed frames are already queued up waiting to be displayed, and you start rendering another frame, your get blocked until one of the two pending frames is displayed at the next screen refresh.

This is actually very desirable behavior. Depending on the system and settings, some PC type devices let you render faster than the screen refresh rate. The result is that you render frames that never show up on the display, and are simply dropped. If you think about it, this is a complete waste. Particularly on battery powered and/or heat constrained devices, you don't want to do any unnecessary work. Throttling the rendering to match the screen refresh rate makes complete sense.

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is exactly accurate and clear. I would like to make it more simple.

Assume you render function is as follow:

```
onDrawFrame() {
    time t1, t2;
    t1 = getTime();
    glClear();
    t2 = getTime();
    logOut(t2 - t1); // log time would be around 16 ms
}
```

If the refreshing FPS is 60Hz, then the refreshing margin would be approximately 16.666 ms. Now if your rendering time is smaller than 16ms, it will be meaningless because GPU would not be able to process the updated calls (Well GPU has a queue to buffer these calls, but the queue is not unlimited anyway).

So GPU **delayed the use and return** of your `glClear()` call in order to avoid meaningless GL calls.

If you did another experiment like below, you would probably find the logged time much smaller.

```
onDrawFrame() {
    time t1, t2;
    t1 = getTime();
    glClear();
    t2 = getTime();
    sleep(10);       // sleep 10 ms
    logOut(t2 - t1); // log time would be around 5 to 6 ms now
}
```